# Can't get round cornes to work on Google Maps in IE8

Tags: css, google-maps, internet-explorer-8, css3pie

I am currently trying to get an embedded Google map to have round corners. The whole corporation, for which the website is intended are currently terribly stuck with their win7 + ie8 solution, and their project planning team, have no idea what a hassle it is to include something as simple as round corners across the entire website and getting it to work in IE8.

Anyways I have scanned the interwebs and have yet to figure this out. I am currently using the CSS3Pie library for the rest of the site and the recent solution I tried is listed below(which i found at http://blog.bandit.co.nz/post/31510944554/how-to-round-the-corners-of-a-google-map-embed):

```
#mask {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    behavior: url(../PIE-1.0.0/PIE.htc);
}

#mask iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    z-index: 50;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    behavior: url(../PIE-1.0.0/PIE.htc);
}
```

Sadly this works all the way down to IE9 but no further, so i was hoping you geniuses had encountered this problem before and could help out.

Comment: Beware: Google is [planning to discontinue support  of Internet Explorer 8 (IE8) for the Google Maps JavaScript API v3 around August 31st 2015](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3-notify/pBmDNwX48Q4)

Comment: Create an image that looks like the outside of a rounded corner. Slap it on top of the corner of the iframe. http://fiddle.jshell.net/MrLister/8L0s32tn/1/show/

Comment: Hmm thats a good idea, thx for the feedback.

Comment: Seriously, in 2015 you don't need `-webkit-` or `-moz-` prefixes for `border-radius`. If you find a single user with a browser which needs either of them I'll be astounded.